# Shell script to run PLP/SQL procedure requiring terminal input and then move the shell process to background

Tags: bash, shell, plsql, procedure

I am running a PL/SQL inside a shell script that accepts IN parameters for the procedure from the shell  terminal. The entire process takes about 4 hrs. I know that we can enter ctrl+z to suspend the process and restart  by using the bg command to send the process to the background. Is there a way I can enter the input through the terminal and send the process to the background without suspending it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, then a wrapper script that reads the parameters seems sufficient. It can start your PL/SQL script as a background process by using the ampersand:

```
me:~/$ cat ./wrapper.sh 
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the first parameter: " p1
read -p "Enter the second parameter: " p2
read -p "Enter the third parameter: " p3
read -p "Enter the fourth parameter: " p4

./plsql.sh $p1 $p2 $p3 $p4 &
pid=$!
jobs -l
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep $pid
```

Here's how that looks in action:

```
me:~/$ ./wrapper.sh 
Enter the first parameter: a  
Enter the second parameter: b
Enter the third parameter: c
Enter the fourth parameter: dd
[1]+ 151367 Running                 ./plsql.sh $p1 $p2 $p3 $p4 &
me      151367  0.0  0.1   6940  3404 pts/2    S+   06:49   0:00 /bin/bash ./plsql.sh a b c dd
```

Comment: My shell is korn. This methos is nto working in korn. The parameters are not saved when plpsql.sh runs

Comment: you've put _bash_ in your question tags, not korn.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the shell to put *itself* into background, try an `exec`:

```
if [[ -n "$stuff" ]]
then sleep "$stuff"
else read -p "gimme some input: " stuff
     export stuff
     exec $0 &
fi
```